# How to Document restful API's developed using spring MVC 3.0.7

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, documentation

I am working on project which uses spring framework 3.0.7. I have developed restful APIs using spring MVC 3.0.7 with XML configuration as my project already has spring 3.0.7 dependencies. So far so good all things are working fine but the struggle started when my manager asked me for documentation for restful API's developed. I have went through so many articles but none of them worked, because the spring version is very old. Any help to generate documentation appreciated or at least WADL file generation also fine.

I have tried swagger but it is not supported for spring MVC 3.0.7 - (May be I am configuring it wrong). I am not interested in creating test cases.

Comment: Spring 3.07 or Spring Boot 3.0.7 as that will make a huge difference!. Spring 3.0.7 hasn't been supported for about 10 years, whereas Spring Boot 3.0.7 uses Spring Framework 6.0.

Comment: Spring 3.0.7 only (non boot). yes there is no support also  for spring 3.0.7 but my project has these jars and i am not allowed to change it.

Comment: Spring 3.0.7 was released 12 years ago (almost 13) and I doubt there is support for something like swagger or anything for such an old version of Spring. You should really upgrade to something newer, not just for swagger but also from a security point of view.

Comment: It is a corporate app I didn't had that control, This project is not entirely built on spring 3.0.7 but with client framework which is good enough, Now we made our facade methods as restful methods using those spring 3.0.7 jars (because there is no need to add any other dependencies). Yes upgrading to newer version is great but that is out of scope for my task, Now I just need a way to document those restful api's or at least need to generate wadl.

Comment: you can hand write the OpenAPI since you are not generating code with it.  It's not super difficult.  If you have questions about how to write it, just ask.

Comment: @JeremyFiel Thanks! I am not familiar with it, any tutorial or guiding article would be helpful.

Comment: Still I am searching for a way to document my restful apis. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks